# Android 10.1" tablet that supports Android 5.1 (or Cyanogenmod 12.1) or higher

Tags: android, tablet

I am looking to replace an ASUS Transformer (TF101). I like the 10.1" form factor as I use it for watching videos more than I use it as an eReader. One of the features I liked about the Transformer was that I could install Cyanogenmod on it as well.

I'd like to upgrade to something more modern. The Transformer has not received a Cyanogenmod update since version 10. It hasn't received an official Android update since before that.

The problem I have in looking for a replacement is that tablets that support the new versions of Android out of the box are smaller form factors (7-9"). The 10 inch ones all seem to be on KitKat or Ice Cream (Android 4.x) versions.

Requirements:

- Supports Lollipop or Marshmellow (Android 5.0 through 5.2)
- Supports Cyanogenmod 12.1 or higher
- Has decent speakers is a must - I want to be able to set the tablet upright on a table about 3 feet in front of me and hear the sound (the TF101 did not meet this requirement)
- 10.1" form factor
- A microSD slot would be a very nice to have
- A keyboard accessory is optional
- A semi-sturdy case that allows me to prop the tablet up should exist for the recommendation

My price range is roughly $500-600, but if such a tablet doesn't exist in that price range, I'm open to something a bit more expensive.

Comment: Does the tablet have to support both >= Android 5.0 *and* >= Cyanogenmod 12.1? Also, would you be willing to go for a little bit large display size, such as 10.5"?

Comment: A larger display size is fine. As for supported version, either is fine. It does not have to support both.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to go for a little bit larger screen and no official support for Cyanogen, then you might like the [Dell Venue 10 7000](http://www.dell.com/us/p/dell-venue-10-7040-tablet/pd?oc=ftcwp01s&model_id=dell-venue-10-7040-tablet) ($499). It has:

- 10.5" screen (a bit larger than you wanted, but not by too much)
- Support for Android Lollipop 5.0
- Good speakers, better than most Android tablets
- MicroSD card reader
- [Optional magnetically attachable keyboard](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=580-ACWO), which is also a stand (not included, but can be bought for an additional $160)
- [Carrying case](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=460-BBQM#Overview) (not included, but can be bought for $20) (not a stand)

Comment: I've figured out why this one never showed up in my searches. [Amazon lists it as running Windows](http://www.amazon.com/Dell-Venue-Pro-7000-Refurbished/dp/B00RNF9TXY) and I can't find a 10" one that runs Android there.

Answer (score 1):

I own the [Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (T530) WiFi edition ~260€](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00JL6KMRA) ([LTE Available ~290€](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00JL6KMRA/)) running Android 6.0.1 through an unofficial CyanogenMod port, which works well. The sound is loud and clear, but really depends on source quality sometimes.
It has:

- 10.1" screen
- Supports Lollipop 5.0.1 (up to 6.x by community)
- Decent speakers
- MicroSD card reader
- Cases with stand and/or keyboards (not included, around 20-40€)

[image: Galaxy Tab 4 10.1]

Comment: Just noticed that this is from 2015. Dang.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but if you are looking for a cheap tablet, you could try a [Yuntab K107](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I64QIW0) for $81.

[image: Picture of Yuntab K107]

Specs:

- 10.1 inch, 1280x800 IPS screen
- 1.3Ghz quad core processor
- 1GB RAM (1033Mhz?), 16GB ROM (on most models, only 1.5GB is in the internal memory block and the rest is an internal SD card)
- Wi-Fi (802.11abgn), Bluetooth 4.0, 2G/3G
- Slots for microSD (up to 32GB) and 2 SIM cards

Pros (for your purpose):

- 10.1" screen
- No CM/LineageOS, but does have Android 5.1
- Good audio quality
- Good screen (not an AMOLED though, so no good blacks)
- Supports 1080p30 video
- Several optional accessories, such as a [non-keyboard case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XGDL1TR), a [keyboard case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071KSSPQ6), and a [silicone case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073XKC5GG).

Cons:

- Cheap
- Some users have reported defects (like lines on the screen)

If something cheap isn't for you, you could alternatively get a [Samsung Galaxy Tab A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EUC7NAI) for about $280.

[image: Samsung Galaxy Tab A picture]

Specs:

- 10.1 inch, 1920x1200 screem
- 1.6Ghz octa-core processor
- 2GB RAM @1866Mhz, 16GB ROM
- 802.11ac Wi-Fi, Bluetooth 4.2

Pros (for your purpose):

- Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
- 10.1" AMOLED screen
- Supports 1080p60 (not 4k)
- Lots of accessories

(I personally haven't used the second device listed, but it is a lot better then the first one if you are not on an extreme budget)